# How to determine if a process is a web browser?

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to check which web browsers are currently running. I can of course manually provide a list of web browsers:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -in @('chrome','firefox','msedge','iexplore')
```

But I'm wondering if there's a property on the process objects, or if PowerShell or .NET has a built-in method for determining if a process is a web browser. Or, maybe there's an enumerator that lists web browser process names or something?

Comment: i don think that theres a specific definition to identify web browser processes, here is something that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451756/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-a-browser-open-in-c-sharp

Comment: It really would help if you explained [why you want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What do you consider a web browser? If I write an app that uses an external HTTP service, is my app a web browser? What if the service is a web page?

Comment: One could also check out which processes [have open TCP connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to ports 80/443, but this misses proxy ports.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator thanks! yours seems to be the most relevant answer

Comment: @Corvus a web browser is pretty self-explanatory for most people but I provided a few examples in my question in case you were confused

Comment: @jeremywat,  
jmvcollaborator's comment links to a post whose answers do precisely what you were trying to _avoid_, namely to _hard-code_ a list of process names identifying _well-known browsers_.
By contrast, Corvus' comment addresses your intent of identifying web browsers processes _in the abstract_, and - rightfully, it seems to me - points out that there is no simple criterion that
would identify such processes, given that any application is free to embed web content in it.
Thus, Corvus' comment appears to be the more relevant one, though vonPryz's criterion may work well enough..

Comment: Web browsers do not identify as web browsers ;-)

Comment: @mklement0 I appreciate your input! If the answer's no (as stackprotector pointed out), then that's totally fine and it answers my question! But questions like "does XYZ app that happens to reach out to the Internet count as a web browser??" are not helpful, to be honest. We all know what web browsers are. But I've received my answer so again I appreciate your help!

Comment: My pleasure, @jerdub1993. Well, I'd say that _combining_ the comments made by stackprotector, Corvus, and vonPryz paints the most helpful picture, and since no one has posted an answer yet, I encourage you to post one of your own with a summary.